# c# finding all private IP addresses between 172.16 and 172.31

Tags: c#, ip-address

I am trying to find if an IP address is within 172.16.0.0 and 172.31.255.255 (Class B) IPs. If it is, consider this to be a private address and therefore do something with it. But I can't be certain what I have done is correct. The code I have done to try to achieve this :

```
 // The requested IP
 System.Net.IPAddress IP = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(uri)[0];

 // Get the long values of the two IPs in question
 long startIP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("172.16").Address;
 long EndIP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("172.31").Address;

 if (IP.Address >= startIP && IP.Address <= EndIP)
 {
    // OK the requested domain is an internal one so lets return this..
    return true
 }
```

I can't really test this as I don't have a 172. domain. So I hope you can understand why I've asked this.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a 172 'domain' to test this?

Comment: Write unit tests... problem solved.

Comment: To make it testable, have the `startIP` and `EndIP` values be passed into the method/otherwise configurable. Test it within an IP range you do have and then set it to the "production" value when you are done testing.

Comment: If you just need to know if is working or not you can change temporary the ip range using the range you actually have in your machine...

Comment: Q: Shouldn't `EndIP` be `System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("172.32")` and test with `< EndIP`?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Yes as the code above wouldn't work for 172.31.255.255 and below. I guess I was asking for if the `.Address` code was correct. But good spot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to check the individual bytes:

```
    System.Net.IPAddress ipAddress = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses("www.google.be")[0];
    byte[] addressBytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();
    if (addressBytes[0] == 127
        && addressBytes[1] >= 16
        && addressBytes[1] <= 31)
    {
      // found
    }
```

Comment: Yes this is more elegant and looks more reliable. Thanks!